# cross-refence link to a function/class in a different submodule

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

As a simple example, in the following code of 2 submodules (`a.py` and `b.py` in the same directory). The link to the same submodule function `` :func:`hook` `` works but not the link cross-referencing to a different moduel, ie, `` :func:`foo` ``. I also tried the syntax of `` :func:`.a.foo` `` - still does not work. How can I cross reference to `a.foo()`?

```
# script a.py
def foo():
    '''foo func'''

# script b.py
def hook():
    '''hook func'''

def spam():
    '''spam func.
    :func:`foo`
    :func:`hook`
'''
```

Comment: I think you are close. Try fiddling with the Python dotted path. Perhaps `:func:\`a.foo\`` or `:func:\`parent.a.foo\``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html):

> Normally, names in these roles are searched first without any further
>   qualification, then with the current module name prepended, then with
>   the current module and class name (if any) prepended. If you prefix
>   the name with a dot, this order is reversed.

In that case, `` :func:`.a.foo` `` means an object named `a` inside of the module `b`. It will look for `b.a.foo` function.

You should try `` :func:`..a.foo` ``, which will point to `b..a.foo`, or just `a.foo` (cannot check that locally now, sorry; but I remember I was using that syntax before).

But note, that `a.py` & `b.py` should be the modules, i.e. importable under their name. If they are just the scripts, and located not in a package (no `__init__.py` files up to the root of the project), there is no way to cross-reference with these roles.

You can try to use [:any:](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#role-any) role — `` :any:`foo` `` — and hope that it will find the object in the general index of the described objects.